# Laravel 5.1 global scopes... Where should I go?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Well, I've started with Laravel just a few weeks ago, so sorry if I'm repeating something obvious but... here's the thing:

I've got a couple of query scopes in a Photo model:

```
public function scopeSkipFirst($query) 
{
    return $query->where('id', '>', 1);
}

public function scopeSearch($query, $search) 
{
    return $query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
}
```

Now, I want the first one to be executed everytime I make an Eloquent query by that model,  like in `Photo::all()`; and I want the second query scope to be available to any other model.

What's the best practice way to do this? Are both scenarios `global scopes`? I've been reading a few posts (like [this one](http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/)), but I have no clear ideas about which documentation should I refer (Laravel's 4.2 # `Global scopes section`; 5.1 Eloquent's # `Events`; ¿?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want all of your models to have a `scopeSearch()` method, then it would make sense to move it to a trait and then apply that trait to your models. Something like `Searchable`:

```
trait Searchable
{
    public function scopeSearch($query, $search) 
    {
        return $query->where($this->getSearchField(), 'LIKE', "%$search%");
    }

    protected function getSearchField()
    {
        return 'title';
    }
}
```

I’ve also made the column configurable as not all models may have a `title` column. For example, when I create an `Article` model in my applications I’ll have a `headline` column instead of `title`.

With the above trait, you can make a model searchable by implementing the trait:

```
class Photo extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
}
```

You don’t want to make it a global scope. Global scopes are applied to *every* query. Not every query is going to be a search query, and there also won’t be anything to pass as a search query.

The `scopeSkipFirst()` method, *could* be made a global scope if you wanted that to apply any time you queried your `Photo` model, but I can’t think of a reason why you would want to always skip a particular record. Why have it in the database if you never want to display it?

Comment: Hey, thanks! And what documentation would you recommend for global scopes in Laravel 5.1? In the official docs at least I'm having troubles to find it... (Forget about the `scopeSkipFirst()`; just a dumb method to test/exemplify things).

Comment: I’m not sure why the section was removed in the 5.1 docs rewrite, but a section exists in the 5.0 version: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: OK, nice! Thanks again.